# How to add uri prefix in haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I have a haproxy configuration like this:

```
frontend api
    mode http
    default_backend tomcat

backend tomcat
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.0
    server tomcat1 10.0.0.1:1234 weight 1 maxconn 512 check
    server tomcat2 10.0.0.2:1234 weight 1 maxconn 512 check
```

This works, but the urls have to be like: http://api.example.com/project/api/get-something and we'd like to set haproxy somehow so that the url http://api.example.com/api/get-something will get to the same result.

I tried to add the url prefix:

```
    server tomcat1 10.0.0.1:1234/project/ weight 1 maxconn 512 check
    server tomcat2 10.0.0.2:1234/project/ weight 1 maxconn 512 check
```

but it's not supported. Is there a way I can do this only using haproxy? I don't want to set up an apache just to proxy for tomcat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my understanding, you want to rewrite `/api/` to `/project/`.

If yes, then add the line below to your backend configuration:

```
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /api/(.*)     \1\ /project/\2
```

Note that you'll have to enable the option http-server-close on both the frontend and the server for the rewrite rule to be applied to all the requests in a session.